# How to determine closest date

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, razor

I am a little confused about how or what the best way to determine what the closest date is to `DateTime.Now` is.

In my table, everything needs to be timestamped. And on a page, I need to be able to retrieve everything from the table only if the date is the closest date to now.

How would I go about this?

I am using `DateTime.Now` when inserting dates into the Database, and the format is like:

```
5/07/2011 5:28:57 PM
```

Comment: 'Closest' suggests rounding, ie 11pm would be the _next_ day. That is not customary, normally we truncate timestamps to find the Date.

Comment: Yes! I knew I had forgotten a better word for what I was thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY TimestampColumn DESC
```

Consider storing time in **UTC** - `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: What if there are some items in the future in the table? (It's not clear from the question whether that's a possibility.)

Comment: @svick - words `timestamp` and `DateTime.Now` are a good clue ;-)

Comment: @Jerry - because there's no point in wasting CPU cycles on something that will never happen. YAGNI.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my suggestion:

```
declare @DateTimeNow datetime = getdate()

select TOP (1)
     RecordId
    ,MyDateColumn
    ,abs(datediff(s, MyDateColumn, @DateTimeNow)) as Diff
from 
    MyTable
order by 
    abs(datediff(s, MyDateColumn, @DateTimeNow)) asc
```

Do *not* forget to use ABS()!

Comment: Adding ABS() will allow you to include queries for page contents based on any date, not just the current date (now) although it will still support now just fine.

Comment: I also want to add a note that you cannot really use 'ss' (milliseconds) for this test because you will likely get an overflow. You should use 's' (seconds) to guard against that.

Answer (score 1):

Do you only have past dates, meaning, will you ever have a date that is newer than `DateTime.Now`? If not, you could get by with a simple `Order By` on the date column selecting the newest date.  Otherwise, you'll need to get a date difference between your `DateTime.Now`, and order by that result. e.g.

```
SELECT TOP 1
   columnDate
FROM table1
ORDER BY DATEDIFF (ss,@passedInDate,columnDate)
```

This would essentially look for all future and past dates using your @passedInDate (DateTime.Now) as the qualifier *or* base date.  I'm using seconds as the time interval to compare in my example, but you can change that to whatever makes the most sense for you.

Also, you shouldn't need to pass in `DateTime.Now` to SQL server, as you can use the built in `GetDate()` function.

Comment: First, `ss` can't be in single quotes. Second, this will return the date furthest in the past, not closest to the current date, because `DATEDIFF` will return huge negative numbers for them.

Comment: huh, I'm slow, but the second issue still stands.

Comment: This isn't a millisecond, `ss` an abbreviation for second. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL you could use DateDiff:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

or in C# you could use TimeSpan:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx#Y3719

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DD, getdate(), DATE))
```

This should sort your rows by the closest date, past or future. If you need it more precise then just days, change DD to something else, as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: Your suggestion does not get the closest, just sorts. Add TOP1.